# Vertical Text in a Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table with a lot of columns.  So I want to create column headings with the text vertial with something like

```
  <tr><td style="vertical???">Vertical</td>
      <td style="Vertical???">Heading</td>...</tr>
```

Nothing fancy.  No fancy offsets.  Just vertical text in a cell.

It would end up something like

```
V   H
e   e
r   a
t   d
i   i
c   n
a   g
l
```

I have tried many variations of floats and transform-origin but have failed to do this simplest thing.  Weird text outside the box, easy.  But a simple table heading, no.

Is it possible without resorting to absolute positioning and other gross hacks?

Comment: Have you read over [CSS/text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)? Might be helpful

Comment: @Paulie_D the duplicate looks a bit out of date ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [CSS/text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation). But it doesn't change the width of `td` so made trick used `div` inside of td for which you want vertical text.

**Here is the working example:**

```css
.vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
padding-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Vertical</th>
    <th>Heading
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="vertical">Vertical</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="vertical">Heading</div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="vertical">Vertical</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="vertical">Heading</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice. Please be aware of browser support of the Edge browser however: https://caniuse.com/#search=text-orientation. That said, it does look like they will support `text-orientation` in the future ;).

Comment: Could you elaborate why the `writing mode` and `text-orientation` css-properties do not work on a node with `display: table-cell`?

Comment: Thanks.  The Div does not seem to fix the width problem, but I can hack that.  I was looking at the wrong place, transforms instead of Vertical Text.

Comment: Actually sideways-lr is what I wanted.  I never did figure out how to get it top to bottom, but close enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Try this, hope it will be helpful for you..

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;    
}
td {
 writing-mode: vertical-lr;
 text-orientation: upright;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th colspan="2">Telephone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bill Gates</td>
    <td>55577854</td>
    <td>55577855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How is this supposed to be helping here? It 's just showing horizontally

Comment: @B001ᛦ which browser do you use ? because it works, , what got mistaken is the cells selector, td instead th .... but the op provided an example with TD.

Comment: I use `Chrome 78.0.3904.108 `

Comment: Thanks. The widths are wrong, but I can hack that. I was looking at the wrong place, transforms instead of Vertical Text.

Comment: Actually sideways-lr is what I wanted.  I never did figure out how to get it top to bottom, but close enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option to add custom html, you can just use linebreaks.

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>V<br>e<br>r<br>t<br>i<br>c<br>a<br>l</td>
  <td>H<br>e<br>a<br>d<br>i<br>n<br>g</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Otherwise I am afraid you will be looking at a JavaScript based solution. Something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener( 'load', () => {
  let verticals = document.querySelectorAll( 'td.vertical' );
  verticals.forEach( node => {
    node.innerHTML = node.innerText.replace( /./g, `$&<br>`);
   });
});
```

```css
table{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td class="vertical">Vertical</td>
  <td class="vertical">Heading</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well yes, that is what I had done.  But it does not look very good!  But thanks for the suggestion.